# Using Mac mini as wifi router

Tags: macos, networking, router, wireless-networking, mac-mini

I have a Mac mini (leopard/4gb ram/2.0ghz core duo) that is currently acting as my NAS and is also connected to my tv as a htpc (netflix, eyetv, etc.).  I'm wondering if I can get rid of my wifi router (its broken) and use the mini for this task.  An Apple TV and 2 laptops would connect wirelessly to this network.  Few questions:

1. Does the internet connection sharing of Mac OS X have ample security for this (wpa2? any special firewall configuration options? etc.)
2. Any 3rd party apps that would be better than what is built in?
3. Is this advisable?  I know there isn't any physical separation of the firewall and my inner network, but it seems if I configure this correctly, there wouldn't be issues.

(I guess I could go harder core and run two VMs -- one for routing, one for my "regular" tasks, but that might be too much for the mini to handle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your mini can connect to the internet via LAN, then it could concieveably perform the function of a basic Wifi Router.

Let's assume your setup is like this:

> `WWW -> Router -> Ethernet -> Mac Mini`

If that's about right, then you can use Internet Connection Sharing to share your Ethernet Connection over WiFi.

1. Apple Menu -> System Preferences -> Sharing
2. Ensure "Ethernet" is selected for your source.
3. Place a tick in "Airport" - this will enable wireless sharing:
4. Click "Airport Options" to configure the ad-hoc wireless network that will be created.
5. Once you're done, place a tick next to "Internet Sharing" to turn it on. You'll recieve a warning, click "Start"

Unfortunately, it appears that ad-hoc networks created in OSX only support WEP, not WPA.

You can also use your Mac Mini as a router by using PPPoE to connect to the internet, and sharing out over Wifi. I wouldn't reccomend this however, because it will directly connect your Mini to the internet without a hardware based NAT Router. If you do this, ensure you have the firewall turned on, and a strong administrative password set.

Comment: The lack of WPA is a deal breaker.  I'll just grab a cheapo router.

Comment: WPA2 is now available in the current Mac OS X version.

Answer (score 1):

Internet Sharing on Leopard and Snow Leopard only supports WEP, as shown below.

If you fancy setting up your own hotspot, then see [coova.org](http://www.coova.org/). (Based on the no longer active [ChilliSpot](http://www.chillispot.info/), which is also [used in](http://www.sbprojects.com/knowledge/internetwork/fon/index.htm) FON's [Fonera](http://www.fon.com).)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Mac OS X Mountain Lion supports WPA/WPA2.
This question answers that.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48300/how-to-share-internet-with-wpa-wpa2-security